# Avenger 220 - seeing a timing miss when I try to throttle

Tags: motorcycle, avenger-mc

So I am noticing the following on my Bajaj Avenger 220

- Cannot start without choke even when using regularly. When I apply choke, it starts ok
- I need to ride for about 2 minutes with the choke engaged. Else ignition goes off. After 2 mins it is ok and I can turn off the choke
- Thereafter when I throttle, it is ok as long as the torque threshold doesn't change. When it needs to send more fuel because I throttle, there is a "bup" that sounds like a timing miss and thereafter picks up again. Riding is not smooth. Same pattern across higher gears

I recently changed the spark plugs and there is a 10% improvement so there is a problem elsewhere too. What else do I need to do here?

Other points

- Bike is 5+ years old, done about 12k kms
- Recently serviced (2m back)

Answer (score 0):

You likely need more ignition parts - coils, spark plug wires/caps/grommets, CDI unit.  See [this listing](https://www.99rpm.com/bajaj/ignition-coil-cdi-unit-avenger-220.html) of the tune-up parts.

Answer (score 0):

The operation of the choke sounds correct to me.  You should need to use it to start the engine.

The issue you have with the throttle would suggest that there is a issue with the carburetor.  It is possible running lean when you open the throttle, which could cause the issue.  I would check the diaphragm and give it a clean and tune.

There are videos on Youtube about carburetor maintenance, for example - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N04WL_oTaoQ